# How do I fix 503: Service Unavailable for Billing Transaction Error

Tags: google-surveys

I'm getting a 503 error regarding billing when trying to start a survey I've created via the API (POST https://www.googleapis.com/consumersurveys/v2/surveys). Is this something I can fix or does GCS need to make backend billing changes?

**Request**

```
POST /consumersurveys/v2/surveys/pbn22yzmfnvaqwsiz2k5jbgx3i/start
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Content-length: 732
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Expires: Tue, 24 May 2016 20:56:17 GMT
Vary: Origin,X-Origin
Server: GSE
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Tue, 24 May 2016 20:56:17 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "error": {
    "code": 503, 
    "message": "Billing Transaction Error: Account must be a service account with billing enabled to start/stop a survey. Use 2-Legged OAuth and contact 'gcs-api@google.com' to enable billing.. Request Id: 5744bff000ff04244be71b067a0001737e3430322d747269616c320001707573682d30352d32342d72303400010111", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global", 
        "message": "Billing Transaction Error: Account must be a service account with billing enabled to start/stop a survey. Use 2-Legged OAuth and contact 'gcs-api@google.com' to enable billing.. Request Id: 5744bff000ff04244be71b067a0001737e3430322d747269616c320001707573682d30352d32342d72303400010111", 
        "reason": "BILLING_TRANSACTION_ERROR"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently we only support starting surveys with 2LO service accounts. In order to start a survey, set up a service account by visiting

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Then contact gcs-api@google.com and request that that service account be added to your company's shared balance. All calls made on behalf of the service account to start surveys will not be billed to that shared balance.

When creating surveys or updating the owners field, you must include in the owners the service account that will be starting the survey and a non-service human account that can be contacted if there are issues with your survey.